# Objects in column of csv file are lists. How do I combine these into one giant list using Python?

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file whose columns consists entirely of lists like ['spam', 'eggs', ..., 'spam']. Ideally I want to aggregate all of these lists together into one giant list, but am running into trouble doing that; initially I thought something like:

```
import csv
with open(<filepath>, 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    lst = []
    for row in reader:
        lst += row
```

So my idea was basically that each "row in reader" would more-or-less be the list ['spam', 'eggs', ..., 'spam'] and that I could just combine these together one at a time, but that evidently ran into some problems. Is there anyway to make this work? Any help is appreciated!

Edit: To give more context, let's say this csv has one column only and three rows, each of which is literally "['spam', 'eggs', 'spam', 'eggs']". The desired output would be:

```
"['spam', 'eggs', 'spam', 'eggs', 'spam', 'eggs', 'spam', 'eggs', 'spam', 'eggs', 'spam', 'eggs']"
```

But the output I'm getting from my code instead is:

```
"[['spam', 'eggs', 'spam', 'eggs'], ['spam', 'eggs', 'spam', 'eggs'], ['spam', 'eggs', 'spam', 'eggs']]
```

So the question is around how to fix this kind of issue.

Comment: What is the trouble that you are running into? Any errors? Please add example input as it's not clear what your CSV file contains. Does your CSV file literally contain columns like "['spam', 'eggs', ..., 'spam']"?

Comment: I tried editing the question to give some more context on what things look like and the issues I'm getting. Let me know if you need more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A file containing `['spam', 'eggs', 'spam', 'eggs']` is not a CSV file. The content appears more like a string literal version of a Python list. Given that you might be better off treating them as Python list literals, and parsing them with `ast.literal_eval()`:

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open(<filepath>) as infile:
    lst = []
    for line in infile:
        lst.extend(literal_eval(line))
```

If your input file contains this:

```
['spam', 'eggs', 'spam', 'eggs']
['more', 'spam', 'more', 'eggs']
['spam', 'spam', 'spam', 'spam']
```

`lst` would end up containing this:

```
['spam', 'eggs', 'spam', 'eggs', 'more', 'spam', 'more', 'eggs', 'spam', 'spam', 'spam', 'spam']
```

Comment: @JoshuaGensler: no problem.